# Textbox doesn't return the value

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I have this class (`Class1`) that retrieves value from a query. Now I would like to make it object oriented thats why I wrote it that way. Now the problem is, The `TextBox` (`TicketNum`) wont return the value and display it in the form. I dont know why. Help.

```
 public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   private String _TicketNum;

    public String TicketNum
    {
        get { return _TicketNum; }
        set { _TicketNum = value; }
    }
}

  public class Class1
{
    Main main = new Main();
    public void SelectTop1()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {

            using (SqlCommand com_retrieve = new SqlCommand("usp_SelectTop1Ticket", con))
            {
                com_retrieve.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
               try
                {                     
                    main.TicketNum = com_retrieve.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show("Ticket Has been saved. Your Ticket Number: " + com_retrieve.ExecuteScalar().ToString(), "Ticket Filed");
                }
                catch (SqlException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The database has encountered an error");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The server has encountered an error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

  protected void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Class1 selectTop1 = new Class1();
            selectTop1.SelectTop1();
    }
```

Comment: Where is the `TextBox` ? All i see is a string property `TicketNum` ! Also your *save click* really doesn't save anything ?

Comment: that should suppose to be the textbox.text. But I donw know how to Place the value inside the textbox

Comment: it is simple:
textbox.Text = yourvalue;

Comment: you need to set the Text property no ticket number

Comment: so how can I do it? I cant place the txtbox.text inside the Class1 because its not the main class, it cannot see the button

Comment: does `com_retrieve.ExecuteScalar().ToString();` is returning anything? But anyways I think you are making it too complicated. It can in a much simpler way.

Comment: @user1954418, see my updated answer to what I think you are wanting to do, it's been hard to understand as you haven't described your problem to the best standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following:

```
public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public String TicketNum
    {
        get { return textbox.Text; }
        set { textbox.Text = value; }
    }

    protected void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 selectTop1 = new Class1();
        TicketNum = selectTop1.SelectTop1();
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string SelectTop1()
    {
        // assign the value from SQL to the response variable
        string response = "test";
        return response;
    }
}
```

Note the following:

- The `TicketNum` property sets / gets the value to / from the `textbox.Text` property
- There is not need (please read **wrong / why would you?**) to create an instance of the *Main* class inside the `Class1` class
- The `SelectTop1` method returns a string value, which is used in the `Main` class (maybe you could even make it static, so you don't need an instance of the `Class1` class to call it)
- The `MessageBox` class is used in WinForms, maybe you should use some JavaScript for alerts

Answer (score 2):

Your string TicketNum will always be empty because you have not assigned it a value.

Fortunately strings do not connect to textboxes automatically, this would be very frustrating.

To assign the string to the text box then:

```
string TicketNum = txtbox.Text;
```

By the sounds of your question then this may not be the case, it sounds like you want a textbox to appear in your form at this point. So to do this you need to create a new textbox for your form. You can do this in the toolbox, or dynamically. I will show you how to do it dynamically:

```
TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
txtbox.ID = "textBox1";
form1.Controls.Add(txtbox);
```

Ofcourse you would then name these textboxes to a more suited name. Then you would then go back to your string ticketnum and update it to call the name textbox ID.

**Edit**

I have answered what your question asked, but from looking at your comments I can see your question was of poor quality. It sounds more like you want to pass the information from a txtbox in the main class to this class. OOP makes this pretty simple. in the main class you need to store the txtbox into a string. Then you need to create a constructor in your new class, then simply pass the string parameter to your new class constructor.

If you are unsure on this, I would advise looking into [Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115.aspx), and for an over all of OOP look into [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd460654.aspx).

**Edit2**

Before SO becomes google, I belive you should read up on OOP again, you have not understood it. In this class you could use inheritance rather than calling the main class in this class, not sure why you would do this anyway. If you read the articles I gave you I would have thought you would have saw your errors by now and fixed this issue.

Comment: I want the value of this line " main.TicketNum = com_retrieve.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
" to be placed in a textbox.But I dont know how. I have tried a lot of ways to pass the value from the outside class to my main class but it all doesnt work.